# Markdown Table not rendering correctly on GitHub Pages

Tags: markdown, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

I am attempting to render the following table in Markdown on Github Pages.

```
---
title: "Abbreviations"
---

| Abbreviation | Definition |
|---|---|
| ADUS | Archived Data User Service |
| APC | Automatic Passenger County |
| AVL | Automatic Vehicle Location |
| DriveNET |
| FHWA | Federal Highway Administration |
| iPeMS |Iteris Performance Management System |
| ITS | Intelligent Transportation Systems |
| MPO | Metropolitan Planning Organization |
| ODOT | Oregon Department of Transportation |
| PSU | Portland State University |
| RITIS | Regional Integrated Transportation Information System |
| VHT | Vehicle Hours Traveled |
| VMT | Vehicle Miles Traveled |
| VPLPH | Vehicles per Lane per Hour |
```

The table previously rendered correctly, then stopped after some changes were made.  I reverted to the format which renders correctly on the live version of the project, and it continues not to render as a table, but rather as a poorly formatted chunk of text with a lot of pipes.  In the current live version of the markdown file, there is no blank line between the `---` following `title` and the table header, and again, it works fine.  Other answers on StackOverflow suggested that tables require a blank line above the table header in order to render correctly, so I added that to this markdown file, but it still fails to render as a table.  I have also tried two blank lines.

The markdown flavor is CommonMarkGhPages - which is different than the live version, however it was previously rendering correctly CommonMarkGhPages and no longer does so.

Any help is appreciated, I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Change markdown processor in `_config.yml` from CommonMarkGhPages to:

```
markdown: GFM
```